# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null core.js:1598 at eval (angular5-data-table.js:130)

Tags: angularjs

My package.json file is

```
{
  "name": "now-ui-dashboard-angular",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "6.0.2",
    "@angular/common": "6.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "6.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "6.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "6.0.2",
    "@angular/http": "6.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "6.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "6.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-server": "6.0.2",
    "@angular/router": "6.0.2",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "2.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "ajv": "6.2.1",
    "ajv-keywords": "3.1.0",
    "angular5-data-table": "^1.0.3",
    "bootstrap": "4.1.0",
    "chart.js": "2.7.2",
    "chartist": "0.11.0",
    "classlist.js": "1.1.20150312",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "4.3.0",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "hammerjs": "2.0.8",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "jw-bootstrap-switch-ng2": "1.0.10",
    "ng2-charts": "1.6.0",
    "ngx-toastr": "^8.5.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "nouislider": "10.0.0",
    "perfect-scrollbar": "1.1.0",
    "popper.js": "1.14.3",
    "rellax": "1.4.0",
    "rxjs": "6.1.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "6.1.0",
    "web-animations-js": "2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.7.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "6.0.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "6.0.2",
    "@types/bootstrap": "3.3.32",
    "@types/chartist": "0.9.34",
    "@types/googlemaps": "3.30.8",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/jquery": "1.10.31",
    "@types/node": "6.0.73",
    "codelyzer": "4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "3.1.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
    "karma": "2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "1.4.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.1",
    "protractor": "5.3.1",
    "ts-node": "5.0.1",
    "tslint": "5.9.1",
    "typescript": "2.7.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your package.json, you are using old version of angular-cli. Can you update your angular cli with latest version and try it again.

I remember this issue is fixed by angular-cli team. try with latest version and let me know.

Happy Holidays!

Comment: i tried command => npm install -g @angular/cli@latest   but still its not working

Comment: i am using.....Angular CLI: 1.7.4      Node: 10.14.2          OS: win32 x64
       Angular: 6.0.2

Comment: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
    at eval (angular5-data-table.js:130)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4053)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask (zone.js:496)
    at ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:485)
    at timer (zone.js:2054)